# Special characters do not display in browser

Tags: php, mysql

When echoing data from the MySQL database I get strange symbols in the text. I've tried `htmlspecialchars_decode()`, but to no avail. The data is stored as a `VARCHAR` in the MySQL database and is displayed as they should when queried in MySQL workbench.

The characters include `'`, `ë`, `è`, `é`, `ê`, ...

How do I get these characters to display in html?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: This question has been asked before. http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: Try this: `<?php
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
?>`

Comment: possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: @lolka_bolka Thanks, I found the answer in that post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
$db = Database::getInstance();
$mysqli = $db->getConnection();
$mysqli->set_charset('utf8mb4');
```

Stolen from [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Answer (score 1):

Have you declared a charset in the HTML of your page?

In HTML5 this is fine:

`<meta charset="UTF-8">`

Older (HTML 4.01) needs something like:

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">`

Answer (score 1):

You have encoding issues.

1. You need to set `<meta charset="UTF-8">`.
2. You need to run query after you set up connection to DB "SET NAMES utf8"
3. If you using PDO need set PDO like this  `new M_PDO("mysql:host={$dbhost};dbname={$dbname};charset=utf-8", $dbuser, $dbpassword);`

Also you can use this function which will encode accents to html entities

```
function convert($str){
     return mb_convert_encoding($str, "HTML-ENTITIES", "UTF-8");
}
echo convert($YourDataFromDB);
```

Hope it will helps